# Difference between basic_istream<>::tellg() and basic_ostream<>::tellp()

Tags: c++, filestream

I was just wondering why the member functions `tellg()` defined in `basic_istream<>` class and `tellp()` defined in `basic_ostream<>` class have different names. Is that because `basic_fstream<>` is derived from `basic_istream<>` and `basic_ostream<>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And how would you distinguish them in bidirectional streams,
like `std::fstream` or `std::stringstream`?  Streams are allowed
to maintain separate pointers for input and output: `fstream`
doesn't, but `stringstream` does.  So you need either a flag to
indicate which one you want (as is the case in `streambuf`), or
you need two separate functions.

Comment: +1 Why doesn't `fstream` maintain separate pointers ?

Comment: Because most (or probably all) file systems don't.  It wouldn't be very useful to specify functionality in a way that couldn't be implemented under Unix or under Windows.

Answer (score 8):

`tellg()` get the position of the `get` pointer and `tellp()` gets the position of the `put` pointer, one of them is the place where you read and the second- where you write in the file. So the two functions do different things and return different values. Why would you think they should have the same name?

Comment: They both position the file pointer in two different classes

Comment: @user1577873 but you may open a file in an append mode so that both pointers are of an interest - you may both read and write to the file.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev No, in a file they always both have the same value. They can be different in other kinds of streams, such as `std::stringstream`.

Comment: @Ivaylo That's exactly what I was referring to, when I said that the names are different probably because basic_fstream<> (for bidirectional files) is derived from the classes basic_istream<> and basic_ofstream<>. Otherwise the names could be the same. This way, it would be less confusing to the user.

Comment: @Potatoswatter are you sure even if you call `seekp` and `seekg`?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Yes, I (re-)wrote the buffering for GCC's standard library and the mechanism which keeps the get and put pointers in sync.