# File handlling in C++: updating a line

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling

I am writing program for Library Management. I have a file *Student.dat* which have four columns. Initially when no book is issued it looks like this.

```
     ---------------Students List ----------------
Roll No.                Name                    Book Issued        Issued Book No.
001                     Abhi                    0                  No
002                     Ashu                    0                  No
```

After issuing book to '001'.

```
 ---------------Students List ----------------
Roll No.                Name                    Book Issued             Issued Book No.
001                     Abhi                    1                       1001
02                      Ashu                    0                       No
```

The roll number of second student becomes '02'.

This is complete issue function in library.cpp

```
    void Library::book_issue()
    {
        //Some code
        fp.open("Students.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
        fp1.open("Books.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        int oldPos = fp.tellg();
        while (std::getline(fp, line) && !found_stu)
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            ss >> roll_n >> s_name >> tkn >> issued_b_num;
               ////////////
            std::getline(ss, line);
            if (boost::iequals(roll_n, r_num))
            {
                found_stu = true;
                if (tkn == 0)
                {
                    std::cout << "Enter Book No. : ";
                    std::getline(std::cin, b_num);
                    while (fp1 >> book_n >> b_name >> a_name && !found_book)
                    {
                        if (boost::iequals(book_n, b_num))
                        {
                            Book::show_book(book_n, b_name, a_name);
                            found_book = true;
                            tkn = 1;
                            Student::reset_issued_book_num();
                            issued_b_num = book_n;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            fp.seekg(oldPos);
                           fp << roll_n << " " << s_name << " " << tkn << " " << issued_b_num << '\n';
                            std::cout << "Book Issued Successfully\n";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found_book)
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Book does not exist\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found_stu)
        {
            std::cout << "Student record does not exist\n";
        }
        fp.close();
        fp1.close();
    }
```

I want to know whether I have used `oldPos` variable correctly?

Edit:
After assigning length of `Issued Book No.` as length of book number, I get repeated record.

```
 ---------------Students List ----------------
Roll No.                Name                    Book Issued             Issued Book No.
001                     Abhi                    1                       1001
001                     Abhi                    1                       1001
002                     Ashu                    0                       No
```

Comment: So what exact problem are you having? You want `002` instead of `02`??

Comment: If you your code is working and you want a code review try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinYork York It is not working, it should print `002` instead of `02`

Comment: See `std::setw` and `std::setfill`.  Set the {field} width to 3, and fill with '0'.

Comment: You cannot just replace "No" with "1001" in a file. The number of characters is different.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you overwrite the file that you read. So if one line would become longer, you'd overwrite characters of the next line(s).

As `002` becomes `02` and not `2`, I'll assume that `No` in the file is followed by a whitespace.  So if I use  to show in a visible manner the LineFeed, the following content of your file:

```
...NO <LF>002...
```

will be overwriten with:

```
...1001<LF>02...
          ^         (end of the write, remaining chars unchanged)
```

So the 3 chars  `No`  are overwritten with `100`, the LineFeed is overwritten  with `1` and the `0` is overwritten with the new `LineFeed`.

If you want to write in-place like you try here, you must ensure that the size of each line remains fixed in all circumstances.  So "No" should be followed by the number of space needed to match the length of a book number.

### Other remarks

It's not the cause of the error, but `tellg()` returns a `std::streampos`, which can be much larger than an `int`. So I'd recommend to prefer:

```
auto oldPos = fp.tellg();   // here you're sure it's the right type
```

Note also that [`tellg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)/[`seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) are meant for input stream and [`tellp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp)/[`seekp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)for output streams. Fortunately, for bidirectional file streams, there is only one position for reading and writing.  But for other kind of bidirectional strings, this is not guaranteed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14522122/3723423)).

Finally, if the goal of your repositionning is to overwrite the last line, read (and found) you should update it from time to time.